# Git pie - Perl oneliner for Git

Tags: bash, perl, git

I often make changes on my code-base and manually using `sed`, `awk` or `perl -pi -e` is not always as efficient as having a simple alias: `git pie`.

Furthermore, because I am working on Cygwin, I cannot do real in-place replacement without a temporary file that I have to manually suppress afterwards.

Last but not least, `sed`, `awk` and `perl -pi -e` touch all the files that make them new from the point of view of `make`. I rather want to touch only the file with real changes so I wrote this Git alias:

```
[alias]

    # Replace
    pie = "!f() {                                            \
        git ls-files -z | xargs -0 perl -e '                 \
            my $eval = shift @ARGV;                          \
            foreach my $file (@ARGV) {                       \
                next unless -f $file;                        \
                open my $fd, \"<\", $file;                   \
                my $content = do { local $/; <$fd>};         \
                close $fd;                                   \
                my $new = do { $_ = $content; eval $eval; }; \
                if ($content ne $new) {                      \
                    open my $fd, \">\", $file;               \
                    print $fd $_;                            \
                    close $fd;                               \
                }                                            \
            }                                                \
        ' \"$1\"; }; f"
```

I am sure some simplifications can be made on this piece of code, so I ask for your opinion.

The usage is:

```
$ git pie s/foo/bar/g
```

I decided to slurp the whole file in memory in order to do multiline regexes which is very convenient sometime despite the performance.

There is perhaps a missing feature: the ability to exclude or include some file extensions only or simply allow this call:

```
$ git ls-files | grep -P '[.][ch]$' | xargs git pie s/foo/bar/
```

I still didn't figure out how I want to do it. One possible way is:

```
$ git pie 's/foo/bar/ if $file =~ /\.(ch)$/'
```

Comment: Why did you put it into a shell function instead of running the `git | xargs` directly in the alias?

Comment: How would you put the replacement pattern in the correct place with  `echo 1 2 3 | xargs echo` ? You need to write it as follow: `f() {echo 1 2 3 | xargs echo $1;}; f`. Do you have a better option?

Comment: This looks pretty cool. In fact I added to my aliases now, thanks.
The only thing I would change is drop the `\"<\"` when opening file for reading, as that's the default mode anyway.

Comment: nice, and by re-opening the file for write the original file isn't being replaced by a new file with a completely different inode as happens  (on unix at least, don't know about windows) with the `-i` options of perl & sed etc.  The only thing I'd change is to make `pie` a standalone perl script in your $PATH (because it could be useful standalone and because reading and editing a perl script inside a couple of levels of quoting is harder than it needs to be, and all those EOL backslashes don't help).  then just run the `pie` script with xargs in your git alias.

Comment: also, IMO the 3 form of `open FH, MODE, EXPR` is fine.  it's a good habit to use it even when you don't need to.

Comment: `eval "s/foo/bar/"` returns 1, not the new value of $_.  Either your example or your code is wrong.

Comment: @OhMyGoodness I am using this code for almost three years and it works perfectly.

Comment: it works but rewrites every file regardless of change.  See my answer for details and a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, `$new` will contain the return value of `s///`, which is 1 (true) or the empty string (false).  This will (almost) never match `$content` and you'll be rewriting every file unconditionally.

You can inject `$1` directly without the pass-and-eval.  This will stop the Perl script altogether in the event of an error, which is probably desirable.

While `my` and lexical `open` etc. are good habits, they're at odds with the design constraints of a one-liner that needs to survive multiple levels of quoting.  For example, `print FD` prints `$_` to handle `FD`, while `print $fd` needs an explicit `$_` argument, else it prints the string representation of that handle to stdout.  Just switching to a bareword-open saves you five characters.

Perl has a mechanism to read whole files specified on command-line and you can shorten your script further by employing it.

Tying all this together, your one-liner can fit in one line with some whitespace to spare.  In 128 columns (plus four spaces of indent):

```
[alias]
    pie = "!f(){ git ls-files -z | xargs -0 perl -0777ne'$old=$_; '\"$1\"'; $_ ne $old and open FD, q|>|, $ARGV and print FD';} ;f"
```